# how to fix the SyntaxError: unterminated string literal when embed php in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

when i try this：

```
var app_app = <?=$app_app?>;
```

i got the error:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
var app_app = '<br />
```

strange,
anyone can help me ?

Comment: Your JavaScript code depends on what `$app_app` contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var app_app = "<?php echo $app_app; ?>";
```

**Note**: You have to echo out `php` variable to define it into `JavaScript` and also wrap it inside quotes

Comment: er... but SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
[Break On This Error]  

var app_app = "<br />

Comment: @user2086007 Have you tried updated one ?

Comment: It is working for sure , if you still getting error, you have to check out `$app_app` variable. To test out marked script just replace `$app_app` with some value like `"value"` and you see result

Comment: um, really sorry~, i got what happened,the Taint( a tool for security) output the error:<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  main() [<a href='function.echo'>function.echo</a>]: Attempt to echo a string that might be tainted in <b>

Comment: @user2086007 It's okay

Answer (score 1):

Add `"` quotes, and try :

```
var app_app = "<?=$app_app?>";
```

Comment: Also need to `echo out` php variable to assign into JavaScript one

Comment: @DaHaKa : `<?=` is the short form of `echo`

Comment: I didn't take attention on it lol

Comment: i got another error: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
[Break On This Error]  

var app_app = "<br />